# Why this question was marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A question of mine has been marked as duplicate, and I don't understand why.

The question is *[What kind of coin was given by Jaqen H'ghar to Arya?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/170503/83101)*, and was marked as duplicate of *[Was the significance of Arya's Braavosi coin ever explained?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56218/83101)*.

These two questions are about the same object, but they ask something completely different: **what I'm asking is if the coin of the Faceless Men could be identified as a regular currency coin**, and the linked question doesn't provide any satisfactory answer about this particular aspect; the only answer that seems to address my original question takes as a reference the show, while I'm only interested in references from the books; I've used only the relevant tags on my question on purpose.

**Since the linked question don't provide an answer to what I'm asking, could my question be reopened?**

**If my question was ambiguous, I could try to refine it and make its scope more clear.**

Answer (score 8):

Well, tooting my own horn, there's an [answer which answers your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/170557/54887) on the Dupe-target page.

Your question, emphasis your own, was:

> **So, do the Faceless Men use their own distinct iron coins, or just the regular Braavosi currency?**

That answer:

1. Is books only
2. Proves from existing evidence that the coins are distinct.

If you think it doesn't, then you have not explained your question properly. You can always edit and explain why your question is different, that will push your question in the reopen queue. But if we do reopen your question, I would be able to copy paste the same answer to your question and it would still apply. Do you see now why your question is a duplicate?

Duplicates are not a bad thing. But still since you feel so sure that your question is different and you meant to ask something other than whether the FLM use distinct coins or plain old Braavosi ones, you should:

1. Edit your question to explain
2. Wait for the reopening Reviews to end

Either it will be reopened or left closed depending on the judgement of the community.

Comment: You provided a lot of references and with those you were able to draw your conclusions; which, incidentally, are the same conclusions that I drew myself; I was looking for explicit references that left no possible doubt: I just think that those quotes do not necessarily give a definitive answer and that the text could be interpreted to support either view. But it's fine, thank you for your usual effort and detailed answers

Comment: @Sekhemty There was already a discussion in the comments section and later [the GoT chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40233067#40233067) on this. This comment is merely here for the record so that others could access the transcript of that discussion.